# How do I delete cookies when users log out?

Tags: 8, users, sessions, cookies

How do I delete cookies when users log out? How can I do this with out modifying any core module?

Comment: Stupid question, but why not use session then you store your data? Or if you need it as a way to transport infos to the browser (for JS), then you might want to use drupalSettings instead. Cookies have to be sent with every request made to your server

Comment: The problem is that not saving to a session and destroy it on logut , the problem is **i cant identify the user is loged out or not in a custom php file inside a module . The session is not getting there .** So i am using cookies to identiy the user logged in or not in the custom file inside the module folder .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imlement [hook_user_logout($account)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.api.php/function/hook_user_logout/8.2.x) and call [user_cookie_delete($cookie_name)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_cookie_delete/8.2.x).

For example:

```
function mymodule_user_logout($account) {
  user_cookie_delete('name');
  user_cookie_delete('mail');
  user_cookie_delete('homepage');
}
```

Comment: What is $account in this ?

Comment: That is the user object on which the operation was just performed. For example the uid is `$account->id()`.

Comment: can u place a sample code using that function so that users can understand easily , my doubt is from where **$account** is come from ?

Comment: I added sample code to my answer.

Comment: Is there a similar method that would work on Drupal 7?

Comment: Both hooks exist in Drupal 7 as well so you should be able to use the exact same code.